# Quick question about number of positive summands in a sum of $p$-adic integers

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, p-adic-number-theory

I've started reading recently on $p$-adic numbers online. Forgive me if the question is silly.

Let $\mathbb{Z}_p$ be the ring of $p$-adic integers and let $a_1, \ldots, a_k \in \mathbb{Z}_p$. If $a_1 + \cdots + a_k = n$, is it safe to conclude that at most $n$ of the summands $a_1, \ldots, a_k$, are non-zero?

I thought the lack of ordering in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ could create issues here, but probably there's no need for that? Also could someone recommend a good book to read on $p$-adics and their algebraic extensions? Thanks.

Comment: No: p-adic numbers can be negative too.  For example, if p = 7, then -1 = 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 ...

Comment: Do you know why I was notified even though you didn't put @Alex in your comment?

Comment: Hmm? No clue Alex

Comment: Remember that any rational number with no $p$ in its denominator is automatically a $p$-adic integer. So, for $m$ prime to $p$, you could have $nm$ summands of $1/m$, adding up to $n$.